# Displaying UI element on main dispatch queue causes element to appear then disappear

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I want to display a progress HUD right before starting a long task, and dismiss it once the task is done. Right now the UI freezes for some time, then the HUD shows for a second before disappearing. After another 4-5 seconds the task is finished and it displays its results, but the progress HUD is already gone.

```
- (void) addProcess:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    });

    //DO SOME VERY LONG STUFF HERE

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    });
}
```

I use `SVProgressHUD` for the progress HUD. I am calling the method `addProcess` using `dispatch_async()`

If I use the old `+[NSThread detach...]`, it's working flawlessly, but I don't want to use it anymore.

Comment: 1 - My bad it was async. It's really confusing with all these. for second - i have tried a lot of different things - it's now like this because i call it from dispatch_async

Answer (score 8):

A couple of things:

1. The key observation is to always use `dispatch_async` unless you need `dispatch_sync`. You don't need synchronous operation here, so just use `dispatch_async` for your UI updates.
2. If you're running `addProcess` from the main queue, it doesn't need to dispatch the first UI update back to the main queue. Obviously, if you're running this from a background queue, you do.
3. The original question had the dispatch to the background queue within `addProcess`, which makes more sense to me (keeps all the GCD stuff nicely encapsulated). You've updated your answer to say that you're invoking this via `dispatch_async([self addProcess])` (by which I presume you meant to a global queue, not the main queue), which I'm less crazy about. I address both scenarios in my code samples below.

So, in short, if you're invoking this via `[self addProcess]` (without dispatching that, itself, to the background queue) I'd suggest:

```
- (void) addProcess:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //DO SOME VERY LONG STUFF HERE

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        });
    });
}
```

Or, alternatively,

```
- (void) addProcess:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
        });

        //DO SOME VERY LONG STUFF HERE

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        });
    });
}
```

And if you're doing ...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self addProcess]; 
});
```

then it's just:

```
- (void) addProcess:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    });

    //DO SOME VERY LONG STUFF HERE

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    });
}
```

Comment: This works very well, I just thought it was a rule-a-thon never to use dispatch_async to update the UI? Isn't this a violation of that principle, @Rob ? - First Time iOS Developer

Comment: @GangstaGraham I don't know where you heard that, but that's not true. The rule is that you never do UI updates in a background queue, hence making it absolutely essential to dispatch UI updates back to the main queue whenever doing anything asynchronous programming.

Comment: I just realized, that dispatch_async is fine for UI, just as long as it only deals with the main queue (as is in your example), I knew something was bad, i just didn't remember what it was, but it doesn't apply in this case, I guess, good job, @Rob